# Unable to load component class org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.BatchPluginInstaller

Tags: java, sonarqube, jenkins-plugins, sonarqube-msbuild-runner, sonarqube-plugin

I'm running Jenkins ver 2.89.2 with SonarQube Scanner plugin ver 2.4
When running the scanner for MSBuild, it appears to be working, I see lines such as this in my logs:

Downloading from http://MyServer:9000/api/server/version...

etc...

But, then it all comes tumbling down when I get:

ERROR: Error during SonarQube Scanner execution
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to load component class org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.BatchPluginInstaller

etc...

Caused by: You're not authorized to execute any SonarQube analysis. Please contact your SonarQube administrator.

But, I believe that the psudo-user that the job runs under is authorized, because things have worked in the past.  I tried re-generating the authentication token, but that did not work.

Some background: I had installed the current version of the SonarQube scanner, but then discovered that it was not compatible with my version of Jenkins.
I had to un-install the new version, then find an older version of the plugin (I found 2.4) to install.

Maybe something was lost in the process of reverting to an older version of the plugin.

People are getting upset that they are not seeing the analysis.

Do you have any idea of what is wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please add the whole stack trace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to fix the problem by installing version 2.5 of the SonarQube Scanner plugin for Jenkins. This was the sequence of events;

- plugin version 2.5 was installed
- most recent sonar plugin (v2.8.1) was installed.  It was incompatible, so
- most recent sonar plugin was un-installed.
- plugin version 2.4 was installed
- "Unable to load component class" errors began to occur
- plugin version 2.5 was installed
- "Unable to load component class" errors are gone.

So, It looks like remnants of the 2.5 plugin were still present when the 2.4 plugin was installed.  Installing plugin version 2.5 appears to have fixed the problem.